# pyperclip works in console but not script

Tags: python, pyperclip

```
$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 20 2017, 18:23:56) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyperclip
>>> pyperclip.copy('The text to be copied to the clipboard.')
```

for example sets my clipboard properly but the following script does not, what is the difference?

```
$ cat example_pyperclip.py
#!/usr/local/bin/python
import pyperclip
pyperclip.copy('The text to be copied to the clipboard.')
print("script is done")
```

outputs

```
$ python example_pyperclip.py 
script is done
```

Comment: You do not give enough context to say. For example, are you sure that the script executed? (Insert a `print()` line to be sure.) Are you sure there are no other processes using the clipboard?

Comment: yes i did try that initially, I will update the post thanks